# Dropdown pushing logo downwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a custom drop-down navigation but when it toggles the logo, in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/OmarAguinaga/pen/vJGxrP) represented by the blue div, goes to the bottom of the navigation. I've been trying to work around this for a while now and would appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class='container-fluid nav'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class = 'nav__btn--toggle u-inlineBlock u-center' onclick="animateNavbarToggle(this); toggleDropdown();">
      <div class = 'nav__btn bar1'></div>
      <div class = 'nav__btn bar2'></div>
      <div class = 'nav__btn bar3'></div>
    </div>
    <ul class = "nav__dropdown">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Work</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

    <div class='nav__brand u-inlineBlock'>
      logo
    </div>
    
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav__dropdown {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 75px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.nav__dropdown li {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 40%;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.nav__dropdown li:last-child{
  border-bottom: none;
 }
.nav__dropdown li:hover{
  background: black;
  color: seashell
 }
.u-inlineBlock {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JS

```
function toggleDropdown(x) {
    $('.nav__dropdown').slideToggle(500);
}
```

After this, I'll try to add a sub menu on the right side, so if you could point me in the right path for that as well that would be great

*(Notice that this is just a bonus for me, I don't care if you don't help me with that so don't downvote for being too broad or something like that. I also saw some similar questions but they did not help)*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you want the "logo" to remain where it is originally?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]? Unable to replicate. And where are you calling the `toggleDropdown()` function?

Comment: Yes, and the drop-down at the bottom of the while navbar.

Comment: @PraveenKumar There is a codepen on the description.

Comment: Ouch. Was trying: http://jsbin.com/xicorifana/edit?output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the logo before the ul, and remove the `margin-top` from the ul. And if you want the toggle button and submenu to be flush with the white header, remove `.nav { height: 75px; }`

```js
function animateNavbarToggle(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("toggled");
}


function toggleDropdown(x) {
    $('.nav__dropdown').slideToggle(500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
body {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 2000px;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
  #NAVIGATION
\*------------------------------------*/
.nav {
  background-color: white;
  height: 75px;
}

.nav__brand {
  height: 68px;
  width: 227px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

/**
 * Navigation dropdown button
 */
.nav__btn {
  width: 22PX;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.nav__btn--toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 22PX;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: coral;
  margin: 4px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.toggled .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 5px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 5px);
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.toggled .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.toggled .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-4px, -4px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-4px, -6px);
}

/**
* Navigation Dropdown
*/
.nav__dropdown {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.nav__dropdown li {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 40%;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.nav__dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.nav__dropdown li:hover {
  background: black;
  color: seashell;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
  #UTILITIES
\*------------------------------------*/
.u-inlineBlock {
  display: inline-block;
}

.u-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
</style>
<div class='container-fluid nav'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='nav__btn--toggle u-inlineBlock u-center' onclick="animateNavbarToggle(this); toggleDropdown();">
      <div class='nav__btn bar1'></div>
      <div class='nav__btn bar2'></div>
      <div class='nav__btn bar3'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='nav__brand u-inlineBlock'>
      logo
    </div>
    <ul class="nav__dropdown">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Work</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel really stupid for not notice this. Thaks man. I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `position: fixed` to your `nav__dropdown` CSS

```
.nav__dropdown {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 75px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Position `fixed` essentially removes the content from the flow of the document window, which makes it not cause any interactions with your logo.
More on position `fixed` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: But what if we don't want the nav to be fixed?

Comment: Then this isn't the right answer for you @Chesswithsean ;p